# What user-friendly distro uses same commands used in Kali Linux?

Tags: debian, kali-linux

I want to use a distro that uses same terminal commands as Kali. I see that Kali is based on Debian, Debian is generally a base and not an end-user OS, so I want some distribution that I can run as my daily driver so I can transition from Windows 8 to Linux (while training on Kali Linux and getting familiar with a distro that's similar to it.)

PS. I looked at Mint and I see it's based on Debian, then looked at the website and found it uses Ubuntu releases which, in my limited experience, is different than Kali in terms of commands and app management but still based on Debian from my read. (*confused*)

Comment: Debian is very much an 'end-user OS'. Just because some find it not as user-friendly as many of the easy-entry Linux distributions such as Mint, Ubuntu, and Fedora, does not make it inappropriate for end-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in terms of commands

Most of the the general purpose command line applications are standardized across all linuxes and this surely includes Kali, since it is a Debian variant.  These things are actually specified by the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm), which is also used by other "unix-like" OS's such as BSD and OSX.  By way of illustration, if you click *"Shells & Utilities"* in the left top box of that link then *"4. Utilities"* in the bottom left, you'll see a list that includes some familiar things.

> in terms of app management

The package management systems, however, are not so standardized.  Debian's `apt` based system is also used with derivatives such as Ubuntu and Mint, so you should be comfortable there.

However, basic use of package managers is not all that complicated, and there are usually GUI front-ends to help, so do not feel restricted in your choice because of that.

Comment: Great, thanks guys. The point of asking is that I don't want to get used to the GUI, Kali's most commands have much broader effect when mastering the Terminal commands, the GUIs there are lacking quite a bit. So I want something that uses same management and commands scheme to get used to it as a daily driver. I think Mint will do that for me. Thank you both, goldilocks and schaiba (Can't vote up for low rep).

Comment: If you intend to use any of the security-based or penetration-testing related applications that are available in Kali Linux by default, you can just install them on a Debian-based distro (like Ubuntu or Linux Mint) using `apt-get install` since all of these use the same repository. Or you can [add Kali Linux's repositories](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) to be able to install any Kali Linux-specific application.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use Mint or Ubuntu, they're both based on Debian, as you suspected, same package management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you like linux mint, and would like to see a version closer to Debian, be sure to take a look at the Directly-Debian-based version, [LMDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php).